# PHP- how to allow only letters in a text field. Also how to only allow numbers in a text field

Tags: php, html

How do I add a input field that only accepts letters. Also how do I add a input field that only accepts numbers. And once the user inputs say letters in a text field that only accepts numbers it gives an error.

```
if(empty($_POST['firstname']))
        {
            $errors['firstname1'] = " Required";
        }

    if(empty($_POST['zip']))
        {
            $errors['zip1'] = " Required";
        }

    <!-- Letters only for firstname -->

    <p>
                <label for="firstname" class="label"><font color="#040404">*First Name:</font></label>
                <input class="textinput" id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['firstname'])) echo $_POST['firstname']; ?>" /><?php if(isset($errors['firstname1'])) echo $errors['firstname1']; ?>
            </p>
    <!-- Letters only for zip -->

    <p>

                    <label for="zip" class="label"><font color="#040404">*Zip Code:</font></label>
                    <input id="zip" type="text" name="zip" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['zip'])) echo $_POST['zip']; ?>" /><?php if(isset($errors['zip1'])) echo $errors['zip1']; ?> <?php if(isset($errors['zip2'])) echo $errors['zip2']; ?>
                </p>
```

Comment: Are you considering javascript as an option?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you can't do this with just PHP and HTML. You could use Javascript to 'enforce' your rules, though.

Comment: HTML5 patterns in the input boxes?

Comment: `<input type="text" name="firstname" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}" title="At least three letters please">` --- this allows at least 3 letters, `<input type="text" name="zip" pattern="[0-9]{3}" title="At least three zip numbers please">` --- this allows at least 3 numbers.

Answer (score 8):

Consider using the PHP functions [**ctype_alpha**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php) & [**ctype_digit**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) in your form validation.

**ctype_alpha** returns true only if validation consists of letters, and will return false if numeric or special characters are used.

**ctype_digit** returns true only if validation consists of numbers, and will return false if alphabetic or special characters are used.

Here's a quick example that will check an array. It will return false since one of the strings has a number in it:

```
$string = array('word', 'number5');
if (ctype_digit($string)) {
    echo "All numbers are true!";
} else {
    echo "Something's not right";
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

> how to allow only letters in a text field.

You can use `pattern` attribute of HTML5 to allow only letters in a text field, like this:

```
<input type="text" name="fieldname1" pattern="[a-zA-Z]{1,}" required>
```

> how to only allow numbers in a text field

Simillarly, make the `type` attribute `number` to only allow numbers in a text field, like this:

```
<input type="number" name="fieldname2" required>
```

Or, use the `pattern` attribute, like this:

```
<input type="text" name="fieldname2" pattern="[0-9]{1,}" required>
```

**Sidenote:** Even though these input fields on the **client side** will restrict users to some extent, they can't be reliable and your only line of defense. Use [PHP Regex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) on the **server side** to strictly validate your input data.

Comment: this helped a lot my man. Also for a text field how do I only allow numbers and letters and no special characters. Its for an address field

Comment: @ShivPatel Make the `pattern` attribute like this, `pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}"`

Comment: @Downvoter, Would you please tell me the reason of this downvote? May be I can learn a thing or two from this.

Answer (score 1):

> You do not need to write any extra code to satisfy your requirement

Following is a example which allows only letters (*both small and capital in any sequence*).

```
<input id="my_id" type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]*" class="validate">
```

Or you can give more constraints like allow only first letter to be capital and reaming in small caps with `pattern="[A-Z][a-z]*"`

To allow only numbers use `pattern="[0-9]*"` and to allow only fix number (*say 10*) of numbers use `pattern="[0-9]{10}"`

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
   function removeInvalidCharacters($input, $allowedChars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz 1234567890')
    {
        $str = '';
        for ($i   = 0; $i < strlen($input); $i++)
        {
            if (!stristr($allowedChars, $input[$i]))
            {
                continue;
            }

            $str .= $input[$i];
        }

        return $str;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For numbers only, here's a snippet I use with jQuery:

```
$('.content').keydown(function(e){
    var c = (e.charCode || e.keyCode);
    if(c<48 || c>57){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: PHP tag makes no sense?

Comment: Well, validating input at the server only is a bit late, it is preferable to prevent unwanted input client-side. Otherwise, you'll have to validate in PHP, send and error message back to the client, then wait again for another input. Client-side control prevents unnecessary back-and-forth between client and server.

Comment: Yes, but you must not forget the validation server-side. Because the javascript can be manipulated from client, and will be vulnerable to attacks

Answer (score 0):

Note : This is for PHP only

If you Want to validate with server side with `PHP` you can use:

```
function validate_string_spaces_only($string) {
    if(preg_match("/^[\w ]+$]/", $string)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

string consiting only of letters, numbers and optional spaces